# How to control HTML page resolution and element positioning?

Tags: html, css

I am not good with HTML. But yes I can understand it well.

I faced a scenario where there was a HTML page with header,footer and many page elements on it.When the page was displayed in browser all the elements would go haywire on resizing the browser window.

The solution that was finally given was putting elements in `<div> tag` and then hit-and-trial with `margin-top attribute` for a dozen of elements on the page.I found it clumsy way of solving this issue.

How can the positioning of HTML page elements be handled in such scenarios in a graceful manner?What can be a good approach while WEB page design so that it looks as it is supposed to irrespective of the size of browser?

Comment: You should look into *responsive design*.

Comment: Indeed, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: Possible double question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492835/element-positions-upon-resizing-browser-or-zooming-in-out/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492835/element-positions-upon-resizing-browser-or-zooming-in-out/)

Comment: @cimmanon : thanks :)..got what i wanted..

Comment: @Mr.Web : its not double question. I am very clear that I am looking for some design principle n the link question is just about solving the problem in code..which is clearly reflected in the answers provided..but yes,somehow both can be linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must check out responsive web design. Head over to the links below and you can get what you want:

http://www.labnol.org/internet/responsive-web-design-faq/21361/

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2012/04/responsive-design-harnessing-power-of.html

Comment: Thanks...good links..